# Location of the endpoints of two parametric curves

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-equations, curvature

I have two curves, $C_1$ and $C_2$ parametrized by $\theta$, the angle of the outward normal with the X-axis.

$C_1$ is given by the following equations (say $r = 0.2$): 
\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{d\theta} &= - \frac{\sin \theta}{\kappa(\theta)} \\
\frac{dy}{d\theta} &= \frac{\cos \theta}{\kappa(\theta)}\\
\kappa(\theta) &= \max \left\{\frac{(1-x)\cos \theta + (1-y)\sin \theta}{\frac{r}{\cos^2\theta} + \frac{r}{\mu^2 \sin^2\theta}}, \frac{-(1+x)\cos \theta + (2-y) \sin \theta}{\frac{r}{\mu^2 \sin^2\theta}} \right\}
\end{align*}

$C_2$ is given by the following equations (say $r = 0.2$): 
\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{d\theta} &= - \frac{\sin \theta}{\kappa(\theta)} \\
\frac{dy}{d\theta} &= \frac{\cos \theta}{\kappa(\theta)}\\
\kappa(\theta) &= \max \left\{\frac{(1-x)\cos \theta + (1-y)\sin \theta}{\frac{r}{\mu^2 \cos^2\theta} + \frac{r}{ \sin^2\theta}}, \frac{-(1+x)\cos \theta + (2-y) \sin \theta}{\frac{r}{ \sin^2\theta}} \right\}
\end{align*}

**That is, the only difference between the curvatures of** $C_1$ **and** $C_2$ **is that** $\mu$ **goes on** $\sin$ **in** $C_1$ **while on** $\cos$ **in** $C_2$. **Suppose** $\mu > 1$.

Both the curves start from some point $(w,w)$ such that $w \in [0.5,1]$ with the initial angle $\theta_0^{C_1}$ for $C_1$ = $\pi/4 + \Delta$. 
For $C_2$, the initial angle $\theta_0^{C_2} = \pi/4 - \Delta$ for some $\Delta \in [0,\pi/12]$.

Domain of $\theta$ for curve $C_i$ is $[\theta_0^{C_i},\pi/2]$ and I am interested in $(x^{C_i}(\pi/2), y^{C_i}(\pi/2))$ for both the curves.

Suppose the initial point is chosen so that the curvature remains strictly positive. I want to claim the following: 
$$\text{If } x^{C_1}(\pi/2) = x^{C_2} (\pi/2) \Rightarrow y^{C_1}(\pi/2) > y^{C_2}(\pi/2).$$

Alternatively, if I can prove the following even that would do the job:

$$\text{If } y^{C_1}(\pi/2) = y^{C_2} (\pi/2) \Rightarrow x^{C_1}(\pi/2) > x^{C_2}(\pi/2).$$

Numerically this seems to hold for both large and small $\mu$. But I don't have any idea how to approach a proof. I don't have much of a clue about how to bound the distance between the two curves.

Comment: What is the motivation for this question? Is it some scattering problem?

Comment: The motivation comes from repeated games. I don't know what a scattering problem is besides a casual reading of the Wikipedia article. But, I won't be shocked if there's some connection.